# ValueError when using image == None

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm creating a fail-safe for my program so whenever the image is not there or `image = None` it will display a message and terminate the program. 
I am using the code below as a way to do this:

```
src_img = cv2.imread('/home/nazar/Downloads/img_4.png', 1)
if src_img == None:
    exit('No such file or direcory!')
copy = src_img.copy()
```

This works if there is no image but when there is an image, it will give an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I tried following the error's suggestion and tried `if src_img.all == None:` and now when there is no image it gives the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'all'
```

is there a way to actually do this without getting these error messages and work if an image is given or there is no image given.

Comment: Just use ‘is None’ check instead of ‘== None’

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the first `ValueError` because `NoneType` does not define an equality comparison against numpy arrays, so the array's comparison method is used instead. Numpy converts None into an object array and broadcasts it to the size of your image. The result of `==` is an element-wise comparison, i.e., a boolean array of the same size as your image.

Instead of all that, you should do

```
if src_img is None:
```

`is` compares the raw references. It is the recommended way to check for None since it is much faster and None is a singleton.

The second `AttributeError` comes from the fact that when `src_img` is None, it doesn't have a method named `all`. Even when it is a proper array, `src_img.all` is just a reference to that method, not the result of calling it.

Strangely enough, you could have totally gotten away with doing `if np.all(src_img == None):`, but you really shouldn't because it's a complete travesty in this case. When `src_img` is None, the comparison is scalar True, so `np.all` would return True. If `src_img` is a numeric array, every element would compare False, and `np.all` would return False. The only time this world give the wrong result is if you had an `src_img` that was an object array all of whose elements were None.